"ChunkLoadError" in Ionic Application When Offline, Causing Modules to Stop Working
I'm facing a "ChunkLoadError" in my Ionic Angular application when using it in offline mode.
Scenario:
My application works fine when online.
When I go offline and navigate within the app, the error appears:
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk <chunk_name> failed.
After this error occurs, other parts of the application (modules, components) stop working properly.
Key Details:
Lazy Loading: I'm not using lazy loading in my app, but the error still occurs.
Service Worker: I'm using @angular/pwa for offline support.
Deployment: The app is built using ng build --prod and deployed on [your server/environment details, e.g., Firebase, Nginx].
What I Have Tried:

Disabled optimization, vendorChunk, commonChunk, and namedChunks in angular.json.

Ensured all files are cached via ngsw-config.json
"files": ["/*.js", "/*.css", "/assets/**"]


Added error handling for ChunkLoadError in main.ts:
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', (event: any) => {
  if (event.reason?.name === 'ChunkLoadError') {
    console.error('ChunkLoadError:', event.reason);
    window.location.reload();
  }
});

Cleared the browser cache and redeployed the app.
Issue:
Despite these attempts, the error persists, and the app modules stop functioning correctly after the error is thrown.
My Questions:

What might be causing the "ChunkLoadError" in offline mode if lazy loading is not used?

How can I ensure all chunks or modules are preloaded to avoid this error?

Is there a way to gracefully recover from this error without reloading the app?




The app should work seamlessly offline with all modules preloaded or cached during the initial load.
No chunks should attempt to load dynamically, avoiding the "ChunkLoadError".
Modules should remain functional even after an error is thrown.
